# is there any type of inline construct I can use to make an external method call awaitable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I want to make the user lookup and group lookup below awaitable so I can call them within a Task.WhenAll():

```
var userTask = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item2);
var groupTask = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item3);

await Task.WhenAll(userTask, groupTask);

var user = await userTask;
var group = await groupTask;
```

I could create 2 1 line methods, 1 method for each of these lookups.  Do you know if there is any type of inline construct/wrapper I can use within the method to make these method calls awaitable, so I can call the methods in a similar way to the example code above?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity` and `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity` is not currently awaitable, but you'd like them to be?  I think that's what you're saying, but their results are also assigned to `userTask` and `groupTask`, which makes them sound like `Task`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, right?:

```
var userTask = new Task<UserPrincipal>(() => { return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item2); });
var groupTask = new Task<GroupPrincipal>(() => { return GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item3); });
await Task.WhenAll(userTask, groupTask);
var user = await userTask;
var group = await groupTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Task.Run<TResult> Method (Func<TResult>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx).  It is a simpler alternative to the `TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)` method or manually initializing `new Task(Action)`

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.

```
var userTask = Task.Run(() => UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item2));
var groupTask = Task.Run(() => GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, inputParameters.Item3));
await Task.WhenAll(userTask, groupTask);
var user = await userTask;
var group = await groupTask;
```